# Reduction to bipartite matching

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

Given an undirected graph with n vertices and m edges, is there a simple way to say if it is possible to delete edges from the graph so that finally the degree of each vertex is 1 ?

Comment: what is the range for n?

Comment: n <= 100 and the graph will not contain any loops but may contain multiple edges.

Comment: loop here means self-loop? or just any cycle?

Comment: here loop means any edge that has the same starting and end vertices, i.e., self loop

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is an algorithm for finding a **perfect matching** in general graphs (the definition of perfect matching is a group of edges such that **all** vertices in the graph are touched exactly once by this group). Obviously perfect matching exists only in graphs with even number of vertices.

To find if such matching exists you can use an algorithm for finding **maximum matching** (the largest possible matching in the graph) and check if it's perfect. [The blossom algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blossom_algorithm) is used for finding maximum matching in general graphs.